# SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 period has expired after upgrade to CU 8

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, license

Hi i have MS SQL with version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

When i use this version and performed Log shipping, there is an error and i check on microsoft doc, the error because bugs in sql and i need to upgrade the sql server with Cumulative Update that i download in here https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=sql%20server%202019

i use the latest CU. at first everything was fine until about 60 days i get error that says `SQL SERVER Evaluation period has expired`. And this happened in 3 servers (Production, DR, UAT). after several weeks after upgrade to CU8, got period has expired.

is it normal? because when doing installation, what i do is next and next

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to run the evaluation edition for production purposes, so I guess it's time to buy a proper license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the version output you provided it states that you're running the `Enterprise Evaluation Edition`. This edition can only be used for a short period (I believe 180 days) before it expires and cannot be used. It can also never be used for production workload as per the license agreement.

**For Production/DR**

If you have previously purchased SQL Server licenses, you need to download your product key from the licensing portal and then follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15) to apply the product key to your instance of SQL Server.

If you have not purchased licenses, speak to your licensing reseller to obtain licenses, then follow the instructions to update your license key.

NOTE: You can upgrade your evaluation license to Enterprise, Standard or Web Edition of SQL Server depending on your requirements and available licenses.

**For UAT**

Follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15) for upgrading your edition, but instead of applying a license key, select Developer Edition, which is free for non-production workloads.

Comment: Nicely answered